# how to make general collision with images in for loop

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, collision-detection

collison but its only working for 1 image

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
     CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(myImage1.frame.origin.x, myImage1.frame.origin.y, myImage1.frame.size.width, myImage1.frame.size.height ), p)) 
     { 
         [pieMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:p]; 
     }
}
```

this will work either for

```
[self addImageSubViewAtX:160.0 atY:190.0];
```

OR

```
[self addImageSubViewAtX:90.0 atY:140.0];
```

but not together

this is method defined by you

```
- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y {
    CGRect myImageRect1 = CGRectMake(x, y, 30.0f, 30.0f); 
    myImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect1]; 
    [myImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_finish.gif"]]; 
    [self.view addSubview:myImage1];        
}
```

Comment: I think you need this if for both images, right?so, put another if may solve   
if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(myImage1.frame.origin.x, myImage1.frame.origin.y, myImage1.frame.size.width, myImage1.frame.size.height ), p))

Comment: i did but not working :( any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to make a method receive some parameter because they are not absolutely the same

```
- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y {
  CGRect myImageRect1 = CGRectMake(x, y, 30.0f, 30.0f); 
  myImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect1]; 
  [myImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_finish.gif"]]; 
  [self.view addSubview:myImage1];

}
```

and then you call it 2 times : `[self addImageSubViewAtX:160.0 atY:190.0] and [self addImageSubViewAtX:90.0 atY:140.0]`

Comment: thanks but where should i call 
 [self addImageSubViewAtX:160.0 atY:190.0];
 [self addImageSubViewAtX:90.0 atY:140.0];

i want them in viewdidload()

Comment: Yeah, you can call them in viewDidLoad()

Comment: perfect now one issue is there
i am doing this for collison but its only working for 1 image 
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view];

 

 
  
  
 
 
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(myImage1.frame.origin.x, myImage1.frame.origin.y, myImage1.frame.size.width , myImage1.frame.size.height ), p)) {
    [pieMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:p];
 }
 
}

Comment: Can you edit the question to add this in as well. It is a long code and hard for me to see. I don't have XCode here